# Pass multiple variables to a function when using pandas.DataFrame.assign

Tags: python, pandas

**Overview**

I'm using `pandas.DataFrame.assign` to create a new column using a function in a similar way to this:

```
def find_break(x):

    date_is_before = df.index < datetime.now()
    under_price = df.Low < (x["Cluster Min"] - false_break)
    all_are_true = date_is_before & under_price
    if (all_are_true).any():
        return df[all_are_true].index[0]


dfClustersSupport = dfClusters.assign(
                    support_broken=dfClusters.apply(find_break, 1))
```

I want to now pass the `thresh` variable as follows:

```
def find_break(x, thresh ):

    false_break = thresh / 2

    date_is_before = df.index < datetime.now()
    under_price = df.Low < (x["Cluster Min"] - false_break)
    all_are_true = date_is_before & under_price
    if (all_are_true).any():
        return df[all_are_true].index[0]
```

**Question**

How do I pass the `thresh` variable when I apply the function here?

```
dfClustersSupport = dfClusters.assign(
                    support_broken=dfClusters.apply(find_break, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add kwargs parameter to [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
dfClustersSupport = dfClusters.assign(
                     support_broken=dfClusters.apply(find_break, thresh=10, axis=1))
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I have multiple parameters do I add them to a list? i.e. `[thresh=10, newvar, 5]`

Comment: @ade1e - not sure about this combinations, is possible use also args parameter by tuples - close `.apply(find_break, thresh=10, args = (newvar, 5), axis=1)`